# Enum With True/False in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, enums

I want to write the following Enum in VB.net:

```
Enum EndOfSession
    TRUE
    FALSE
End Enum
```

That returns True or False  **IN String format** .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An enumeration is a list of numbers.  You can't return a String.  Use `EndOfSession.TRUE.ToString`, or write a wrapper class.

Comment: @Grim When you write the string in the following format, I can use it with string values. But In True/False case, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: You mean you're trying to compare it to a Boolean!?

Comment: @Grim VB automatically takes them as boolean but I wanna use the values in String format.

Comment: No, VB doesn't 'take enums as boolean'.  Please rewrite your question to explain what you mean, what you're trying to do and the code that you've tried.  I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: I'd be worried about `EndSession.False` having a different value (1) than a boolean and some pretty confusing code.  `EndSession` are no longer Boolean, but constants.

Comment: Don't forget [`FILE_NOT_FOUND`](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx) in your enum. But seriously, why use an `Enum` for a `boolean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape those reserved words:

```
Enum EndOfSession
    [TRUE]
    [FALSE]
End Enum
```

Now it works already:

```
Console.Write(String.Format("{0}", EndOfSession.TRUE))  ' TRUE
```

Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Please don't. If you scoped a need for an Enum, make sure it contains values other than `True` or `False`. For those use a regular Boolean value. The benefit of an enum is that it allows you to have more than 2 possible named values. You cannot add an item #3 in this case. Consider:

- True (ok)
- False (ok)
- Maybe?

If you thought of a possible value of `Undefined`, this is called `Nullable(Of Boolean)`.

If you are worried about converting a boolean to its string representation, .NET has built in support for that:

```
Dim b As Boolean = True
Console.WriteLine(CStr(b)) 'outputs "True"
```

So you've just used enum in a way that's completely useless from an architecture standpoint. It's like buying a car only to listen to the built-in radio.